# Button with image and stackpanel with text misses the mouse click event in Windows Store App?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

In my Windows Store App I use a button which has a star shape with some text. I use the following XAML code for the button:

```
    <Button  Name="goButton" BorderThickness="0" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,-91,33,0"  FontSize="25" IsEnabled="True" Click="goButton_Click" >
        <Grid Width="227" Height="222">
            <Image Source="Assets/redstar.png" />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="77">
                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="Tag"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="ist um!"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
    </Button>
```

This is what is the button looks like:
[image: Star-shaped button]

Unfortunately it often happens that clicks in the area of the star are not recognized, e.g. the event handler is not startet. I suppose that it has something to do with the image, for it works fine if I remove the image from the grid. But this doesn't solve my problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Im not much of an expert in Windows Store Apps but have you tried adding the image on the button control rather than in the Grid ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't see anything wrong off the top. You could try a couple of things:

- Instead of click, try the Tapped event for the button.
- Try tapped on the container Grid.
- Get rid of the Grid & put all button content in a StackPanel & then try tapped/clicked on it.
- Go with patterns like MVVM & associate your button with a Command.

Hope these help!